# Print dynamic table from one html page to another html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have table that is dynamically created by adding and deleting rows. I need to print this table on another HTML page using JavaScript. Can anybody please help?

Below is my HTML file that creates the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <!--<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->



 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CLIST</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="profile.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="list.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>Orders</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>       
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Chats <span class="label label-primary">42</span>
                </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">7:00 AM</span>Hi :)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">8:00 AM</span>How are you?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">9:00 AM</span>What are you doing?</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-center">View All</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Notifications<span class="label label-info">32</span>
                </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">4:00 AM</span>Favourites Snippet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">4:30 AM</span>Email marketing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">5:00 AM</span>Subscriber focused email
                            design</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-center">View All</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>          
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Settings</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
    Chat
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
    Notification
  </label>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
     <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
                        <thead>    
                        <tr> 
                        <th class="text-center">Select</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Item</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                        </tr>                        
                        </thead> 
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="text" name="text1" class="form-control" placeholder="Item"/></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity"/></td>

                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>    

         <div id="Input">
                        <INPUT class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="AddRow" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                        <INPUT class="pull-right btn btn-default" id="DeleteRow" type="button" value="Delete Row(s)" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center center-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-fresh text-uppercase btn-lg" onclick="startExec()" >Save</button>
            <a href="order.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">ORDER NOW</a>
        </div>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="func.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

Below are the functions in javascript which I have used to create add rows and delete rows

```
 function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 2) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing the created table to the other page?  Are you planning to store it locally? Is there any server side code that will do this?  How is the other page going to pick up the content?  How are you calling the other page? is it a window.open and then you intend to use JavaScript to write contents to it?  So many holes... you need to clarify this.

Comment: I just want to show the table in order to get the confirmation of the order. I could store it locally as well. The other page is called on click of the button ORDER NOW.

Comment: Then it is simple, you can store the html table itself (do `document.getElementById(tableId).innerHTML) and just AJAX it across or store it in local storage using localstorage API or whatever client side mechanism you choose to use.  The next page will just grab the data from the store and display it. Simplest thing is push it into an innerHTML of a container div or something like that.  But that's not quite right, so you need an actual model of the order and not the representation of the order as HTML table, and so knockout, angular, etc. comes to mind.

Comment: I am new to javascript so can you please help me with the code.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at this.  It's a full tutorial on how to use angular if you are going to use it: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro or http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ if you want to use knockout.  They are both interactive tutorial that can walk you through the process and they pretty much cover what you want to do here. Take a look at this: http://jstherightway.org/ if you need a primer on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
url: 'somefile.html',
success: function(data) {
                data=$(data).find('table#dataTable');
    $('#mydiv').html(data);
    alert('Done.');
 }
});
```

Comment: 1. There is no mention of having jQuery.  just suggesting $.ajax will not make it work. 2. There is a huge gap here that still need to be filled... what's the backend store? How is the next page understand where to get the data?

Comment: The backend store is google app engine. Actually this table stores the items and their quantities and after clicking order now I want to redirect to a page where it'll show his order and he can confirm it.